# Yii how to check if query execution failed

Tags: php, mysql, yii, insert

I M Using YII to develop web application

i want to check if query executed successfully or not

```
$data = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($SQL);
$result = $data->queryAll();

if(count($result) == 0)
{
    throw new SoapFault('Sender', 'Unable to get display information.');
}
```

if code will execute if select query return no result-set. but i want to check if query executed successfully or not. based on that i want to throw exception. then if query executed successfully and returned no result-set then some other exception.

how to do this ? any suggestions ?

Comment: Yii will throw an exception by itself if the query fails due to syntax errors or other problems.

Comment: for service to execute properly i need to throw error explicitly...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
try {
    $result = $data->queryAll();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo 'Query failed', $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: I made a DBCommand with a param and wrongfully added quotes: `UPDATE ... WHERE hash = ':hash'`, the command didn't work but didn't throw an exception either. What should one do in such a case?

Comment: If a query has syntax error or failed to execute on database it throws exception. What do you mean by command didn't work? If you have logging setup-ed you can debug SQL generated by yii (log file in runtime dir).

Comment: What I mean is that the update doesn't take place.
The query _per-se_ has no error, but as Yii adds its own quotes when replacing a string parameter, I guess the quotes I added in the query conflict with that, but the query does not throw an SQL error because the query never gets ran actually.

Comment: Well this is fine i think, can you post the code so I can see what is going wrong? Alternatively you can throw your own exception if no rows effected!

Answer (score 0):

```
try 
{
   $result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sqlQuery)->execute();
   echo  'success';
}
catch (Exception $e) 
{
   echo  'fail';
}
```